# Can i use sketch.js in mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

can i use sketch.js in mobile browser? I developing a system using coldfusion and sketch.js. I had tested on desktop browser and it run smoothly. But when i tested on mobile browser, the last sketch of the sketching is unable to get by the sketch.js. So i want to ask, it the sketch.js cannot function well in mobile browser?TQ.

Answer (score 0):

From the sketch.js web site (at the bottom) - http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/

> **Compatibility**
>
> Sketch.js has been tested on Chrome (OS X), Firefox (OS X), Safari (OS X), Android Browser (Honeycomb 3.1). It suffers significant performance degradation on mobile browsers due to general HTML5 Canvas performance issues.

Comment: i had test intridea.github.io/sketch.js using mobile devices browser like ipad chrome browser and Note 5 chrome browse, the previous sketch will disappear when second sketching is drawn